# Play video without gaining the system audio focus (only play video and no audio) and without stoping the background music

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I want to play background music when my app plays video but without audio that is the requirement.

Comment: share some code, did you try something?

Comment: yes I tried by changing the request focus on video view and it worked.

Comment: share some code, how do u approching.

Comment: I have used muted VideoView that solved my issue. The issue was because of the android VideoView component, it requests for audio focus always and the method is private so we cannot override.